# What are some commonly accepted theories of aesthetics?

Tags: aesthetics, contemporary-philosophy

What are the commonly accepted theories of aesthetics? Other than Kant, I haven't read much work on the topic, so I wouldn't mind hearing suggestions of contemporary works on aesthetics.

Comment: If by aesthetics you mean the formal philosophical study of aesthetics as practiced by professional philosophers; I am wholly ignorant. But I wonder why the word doesn't include the actual state of contemporary culture, art, literature, music, politics, our way of life? That's an aesthetic too. The Nazis had a powerful aesthetic. Hugo Boss designed the SS uniforms, did you know that? And in the same way, the West has a contemporary aesthetic. The previous Pope called it a Death culture. Was he wrong? And isn't this really what the current state of aesthetics is? The real, not the academic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shooting from the hip here a bit, but the thing with contemporary aesthetics is that few people believe there can actually be such a thing. The centrality of personal expression seems to destroy any attempt at a unified theory of aesthetics.

In that spirit, here's a few personal anecdotes. If you downvote them, you're a cultural imperialist! :D

- At the University of Chicago, with Notre Dame, the bastion of Continental Philosophy in the United States, there was [Ted Cohen](http://philosophy.uchicago.edu/faculty/cohen.html), a Kantian, *requiescat in pace*
- As an independent British scholar, there is [Roger Scruton](http://www.roger-scruton.com/), who is also a Kantian

There really is no alternative to Kantian aesthetics other than multiculturalist relativism. As a student of Kant, Cohen, and Scruton, I would simply say that Kant was pretty much right, and that there has not been any substantial innovation in aesthetics.

Comment: Which philosophers, if any, theorise on multicultural relativism?

Comment: For the _pro_ I would say Michel Foucault, for the _con_ Alasdair MacIntyre; neither of these treat aesthetics as such, but their arguments apply.

Answer (score 5):

Work that is sometimes called "[speculative realism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_realism)" or "object oriented ontology" might interest you. Most (if not all) of it is directly in dialogue with Kant. [Timothy Morton](http://english.rice.edu/morton.aspx) in particular deals with aesthetics.

There is quite a bit of work on aesthetics since Kant. Aside from the above, Adorno's "Aesthetic Theory" comes to mind and more recently a good deal of Jacques Rancière's work focuses on aesthetics. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

These links will provide the information you are looking for:

[SEP on Aesthetic Concepts](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aesthetic-concept/), [and on Aesthetic Judgement](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aesthetic-judgment/). Furthermore, here are some nice articles:

```
"Explaining Depiction” by Robert Hopkins

“On the Role of Imagining in Pictorial Experience” by Kathleen Stock

“Photography and Representation” by Roger Scruton

“Transparent Pictures: On the Nature of Photographic Realism” by Kendall Walton
```

And an introductory book: Revealing Art, by Matthew Kieran. Routledge 2005.